# "The visual Studio component cache is out of date, please restart Visual Studio."

Tags: visual-studio, atmel, atmelstudio

I'm on windows 7, using Atmel studio 7.0. When I opened up my project in Atmel Studio, it failed to load and gave this error:

```
The Visual Studio component cache is out of date please restart visual studio.
```

When I closed and reopened Atmel Studio, the same error continued. I also tried right clicking on my project, and selecting "Reload project" but then I got this error:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: url
```

How can I open up my project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple. I closed Atmel studio, and looked for

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\AtmelStudio_7.0.790
```

I deleted this whole folder, and when I reopened Atmel Studio, everything worked fine.

Comment: The version might vary, but deleting the `AtmelStudio_*` files in %TEMP% and starting it back up again did seem to work for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 64):

Using "disk cleanup" to cleanup  temporary files and that did the trick - as I do not have the "amtelstudio" mentioned - so that was not applicable in my case.

Using Windows explorer - click on the C drive, go to properties and the disk cleanup button is on that panel. Run that to clear out temp files and whatever it was that Visual Studio was saying was out of date - so it is removed.

Comment: i got similar error for SQL server management studio after i reinstalled VS 2015 and this solution worked, thanks.

Comment: A colleague had this error with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), cleaning up temp files did the trick, thanks.

Comment: It is working in SSMS 17.6. Error came after unexpected shutdown and then an error pop up when I tried to recover files. After that when I clicked the modify button on stored proc this error came up. Deleting temp folder resolved the problem.

Comment: The solution worked for me. The error came after i installed latest windows updates (1803), then i tried launching VS with this error.

Comment: This solution also worked for me, I had updated SSMS 19.0 to 19.1; error came up any time I tried to open a New Query. Running Disk Cleanup resolved the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Open Run command (window key + r) type %temp% this will open your temp files folder, delete everything. Restart VS

Answer (score 4):

Running as administrator did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Close SSMS
- Delete files in C:\Windows\Temp
- Open SSMS

Answer (score -1):

I recommend delete all temporal files like visual because AtmelStudio_7.0.790 isn't in other versions

Answer (score -1):

Repair worked for me:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features >> Microsoft Sql Server 2016>>Repair.

Answer (score -1):

Start Management Studio as Administrator.. It's worked for me.

Comment: The question even says that he is running Atmel Studio, not Management Studio.